# Export Specific Windows Security Event Logs

Tags: powershell, event-log

I need help on completing a PowerShell script in which I can get specific Security Event Logs and export it to CSV file. Currently, I have this line,

`Get-EventLog -LogName Security 4720,4722,4725 -After ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)) | Export-CSV "C:\EventLogs.csv"`

This does get the security events that i want to get. However, the information it provide is incomplete. It does not include these 2 in the output,

1. Account Name - Account that did the change
2. Target Account - Account that was changed

Is there a way to include these 2 above?

I was told that Get-WinEvent is better suited to do this but i am fairly new to PowerShell scripting so I would really appreciate a little help. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, `Export-Csv` will:

- look at the *1st* input object
- inspect its type and determine the columns to export based on all *properties* the type has.

In your case, however, it sounds like the information of interest may be contained *inside* the type's `Message` property.

Thus, you must use an intermediate `Select-Object` call  with a carefully crafted hashtable in order to extract the information of interest as separate properties that `Export-Csv` will then export:

Here's an example that extracts the account names from the `Message` property and exports them as separate columns:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security 4720,4722,4725 -After ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)) |
 Select-Object EventId, Time, @{ 
   n='AccountName';
   e={ ($_.message -replace '\n', ' ') -replace '.*?account name:\t+([^\s]+).*', '$1' } 
 }, @{
   n='TargetAccount';
   e={ ($_.message -replace '\n', ' ') -replace '.*account name:\t+([^\s]+).*', '$1' } 
 } | Export-Csv 'C:\EventLogs.csv'
```

Note how the first regex passed to `-replace` is *non-greedy* (`.*?`), which means that the *first* occurrence will be matched, whereas the second one is greedy (just `.*`), which means that the *last* occurrence will be matched.

The extra step of replacing line breaks with spaces is necessary, because `-replace` apparently invariably matches line by line.

Comment: Hi. I tested your script and it worked like a charm! However, the only entry i get is the Target AccoutName. Can you include the Source/Subject AccountName and the time the event triggered? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @lapsantos: Please see my update; this is not the most robust way to parse the `Message` field, but it may do in your case. Note that you can add more standard fields as needed, such as `Source`, simply by adding to the comma-separated list passed to `Select-Object` (i.e., by adding to the array of property names).